# How can I get reporting managers of all the employees in my organization from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

How can I get reporting managers of all the employees in my organization from SharePoint in a single API call?

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below REST API to get information about employees and managers

```
/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='Title')?@v='i:0#.f|membership|user.name@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use graph api for getting all managers in single api call

[Get Managers - Graph api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Glad that you found the solution to this problem. Thanks for your sharing.